# form update with file upload laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm having a bit of an issue when it comes to updating a form and and having an file input. Here is what I am working with.

I have a form in laravel 5.1 which has a post method and a hidden 'Patch' method. This works as is should updating the fields that are in the form. However, when it introduce:

```
<input type="file" id="profile_picture" name="image_url" />
```

into the form, i get a:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

laravel error. I have tried changing the

```
 <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='PATCH'>
```

to PUT and it still doesnt like it.

My form looks like this:

```
<form action='{{url("profiles/$user->id")}}' method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

route resource looks like this:

```
Route::resource('profiles', 'ProfilesController');
```

I can't figure out what I am missing here...Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the same form for both post and patch requests?

Comment: this form is used only for an update

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the exact route you are typing out in the "action" parameter matching up with the profile controller's update method.

Try changing

```php
action'{{url("profiles/$user->id")}}'
```

to

```php
action='{{ route("profiles.update", $user->id) }}'
```

Additionally, you could use the [Laravel Collective HTML package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) to simply opening and closing of forms.

Comment: I think it has something to do with my php.ini settings and max upload file size. If I do a file more then 3mb it yells at me on the route level, if I do a small file it pushes it through.

Comment: If that is the case, you are correct. Be careful though, if you are using "php artisan serve" command, you should take note that it uses php.ini of php cli. It is different from php.ini of apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Also for POST Request types, you need to send the CSRF token along with your form data. If you are using laravel blade template in your view, you may use

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

which translates to

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value={{ csrf_token() }}
```

Please refer the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf) for this.